# Copy Ansible output to a ini file with avoiding the delimiters

Tags: file, copy, ansible, output

I got the Ansible output like in the screenshot:

[image: Ansible output need to copy to a property file]

and I want the output like in the attached file:

[image: Need the ansible output like in the below screenshot]

How can I copy the Ansible output to a file in a proper order by eliminating all commas and `\n`?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the output of ansible, a good way is to use [callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/callback.html).

But in your case, the best way is to simply use ansible to write the content of the variable into the file with [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/copy_module.html):

```
- name: Write variable content into file
  copy:
    dest: /path/to/the/file.ini
    content: "{{ the_var.content | regex_replace(',', '') }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

The content will be written into the file with interpretation of `\n` and the comma removed with the [`regex_replace` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters).

I would suggest to review the previous tasks generating this content to avoid the creation of the commas.